# Pegar a classe e o name de um Input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como faço pra pegar a classe (`Class`) do seguinte código ,fazendo uma condição com os valores retornados pelo atributo name.Ou seja, quero que se o `input` tiver um determinado nome no seu atributo name ele me retorne alem do valor do atributo `name` sua classe(class).

Só estou conseguindo retornar o `name` do `input` mas quero pegar sua class também baseado no name  retornado.A condição seria: Se o `input` tiver o `name` `thiago` então me retorne sua classe.

```
<div><input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago" value="num1">numero1</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago" value="num2">numero 2</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago"value="num3">numero 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser utilizado [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) para pegar os elementos com `name="thiago"` e depois com a lista de valores pegar o valor do atributo `.class` com [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)`('class')`, ***exemplo***:

***Javascript Puro***

```js
var els = document.getElementsByName('thiago');

for(i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
{
    console.log(els[i].getAttribute("class"));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago" value="num1">numero1</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago" value="num2">numero 2</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago" value="num3">numero 3</div>
```

***JQuery***

```js
var els = $("[name=thiago]");
$.each(els, function(a,b){
    console.log($(b).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago" value="num1">numero1</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago" value="num2">numero 2</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="classe1" name="thiago" value="num3">numero 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
alert($("[name=ab]").attr("class"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input name="ab" type="text" class="all" value="1" />
```